# Regression with sparse data - binning or other approaches?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-additive-model

A couple years ago, I built a GAM to predict game sales regressing away team, sales to date, event month, and days to event against final event sales using smoothing parameters over days to event and sales to date with a separate model for each home team. This worked very well, and I'd like to produce something similar except my current problem is the new dataset is much smaller and so in a sense is much more sparse. In my old dataset I would have continuous order activity for ~200 days prior to the event. Now I might have an order 90 days out, the next one 50 days out, and then heavy activity in the month before the event. I might see more or less than this but it's inconsistent. If I use the exact same methodology I expect I'll get very poor fit. I've thought about binning teams together with similar characteristics to get more consistent order activity farther out from the event.

How would I go about this, would I sum individual game sales for the selected teams in the same month? If someone could explain the aggregation involved in the binning in detail and what my updated dataset would look like that would be very helpful. Wondering if I could create a cross product dummy variable for each team permutation to still capture unique matchup characteristics, but that would involve 870 permutations so some advice on the practicality of that would be great. Also, is there perhaps another type of model that could handle the sparse data better using the original parameters? Any other thoughts on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from a hierarchical model, where you can learn about the smooth functions from all the data with adjustments to account for the group structure in the data (each home team). It's hard to give concrete advice without seeing your original model specification, but it does sound like you could gain a lot from modelling all the data from all teams in a single model, and which would avoid the need to bin data.